# does apple mapkit works in china on iPhone device

Tags: ios, geolocation, mapkit

I read many articles that Google maps does not work in China on iPhone/Android devices and there are many alternatives like baidu location sdk etc.

Apple's mapkit - does it work in China on iPhone devices ?

Answer (score 1):

Check it out [maps](https://www.apple.com/in/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions)

You can look for each services whether particular provided by apple is available in your area or not.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering maps and displaying annotations via Mapkit within China is no problem at all. However, if you want your users in China to calculate directions, they can only get directions within China. If you have a user in Shanghai who wants to get the route from New York to Washington DC, he'll stare at a blank screen.